# Neuralprophet forecast output doesn't seem to add up

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I would expect the sum of the various decomposed elements of the forecast to equal the yhat/prediction value, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Here an example using a simplified version of the example given in the NP documentation. Here I am taking a simple example data set, producing a model which factors in the

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset for tutorial 4 with the extra temperature column
df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/ourownstory/neuralprophet-data/raw/main/kaggle-energy/datasets/tutorial04.csv")
df.head()

from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet, set_log_level

# Disable logging messages unless there is an error
set_log_level("ERROR")

# Model and prediction
m = NeuralProphet(
    yearly_seasonality=True,
    weekly_seasonality=False,
    daily_seasonality=False,
    n_lags=10,
)

# Add the new future regressor
m.add_future_regressor("temperature")

# Continue training the model and making a prediction
metrics = m.fit(df)
forecast = m.predict(df)

# drop rows with NA
forecast = forecast.dropna(axis=0)

forecast.head()
```

If we then look at the forecast output this gives

[image]

I would expect that the predicted value = future regressors + yearly seasonality + trend + adjustment for auto regression

i.e. yhat1 = future_regressors_additive + season_yearly + trend + ar1

However in the first row future_regressors_additive + season_yearly + trend + ar1 = 73.94814, which is obviously considerably higher that the yhat1 prediction of 58.86

Am I misinterpreting how the components of the prediction should be combined or is there something else going on here which isn't included in the forecast output df?

If I set the lag to 0 (i.e. no auto-regression) then yhat1 = future_regressors_additive + season_yearly + trend

What's going on here?. I've tried looking through the NP documentation but it all seems to suggest that summing the decomposed elements of the prediction should = yhat1?